# How to put date to right name of a week days in each month and without weekends

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula

I have this monthly work report sheet. And I don't know how to make some autofill for column B which will provide a number of a day for a right name of a week day in column A.

[image]

I was only able to find formula which gave me date of first work day in first week of the month.

> This will take month and year from B2 and B3 cells and generate first
> day in month:

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(1;B2;B3));"dd.mm.yyyy")
```

> This will find from first day in mnoth the first working day.

```
=TEXT(WORKDAY(EOMONTH(R2;-1); 1);"dd.mm.yyyy")
```

But the first problem is that the each next month a first work day starts in different name of a week.
And second problem is that the each week has a "Sum:" after each friday.

Please, can someone provide me any solution via formulas or macro?

Comment: Is it specifically column B that you are wanting to populate with the date value from the day name? Its very easy to get the dayname from the date, im not so sure about getting the date from the day name, could you change your process so its the dayname that populated

Comment: Similar to A.Steer, it would be much simpler to have the date provided, then dictate the weekday name based on said date.  If you absolutely cannot go that route, you'll need to determine the weekday name for the first of the month... you then `Find` the first instance of that weekday name in your column A, then begin appending your dates to `Columns(2)` in your preferred format starting on that found row.

Comment: Is your date format `Day.Month.` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really poorly written tbh, but maybe you can make use of it.

Basically, just select the cell that has the first day of the month and enter the date:

[image: Img1]

The code will then use the current date and work its way down your list until it runs into `Sum:` at the bottom or the current month ends and put in the date using `dd.mm` format (feel free to change this in the code).

If it finds `Sum:` to its left, it will add 3 days to its current date.

Otherwise, it will add 1 day to its current date.

Worth noting that it looks for the name of the current month in cell `B2`

If you want to add a period after the format (like you showed in your screenshot), just add an extra `.` to the line `Format(aDate, "dd.mm")`

It would become `ActiveCell.Value = Format(aDate, "dd.mm.")`

[image: Img2]

```
Sub GenerateDates()
Dim aDate
aDate = InputBox("Enter Date of Current Cell", "Enter Date of Current Cell")
If IsDate(aDate) Then
    aDate = DateValue(aDate)
    Do While ActiveCell.Value = ""
        ActiveCell.Value = Format(aDate, "dd.mm")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Sum:" Then
            aDate = DateAdd("d", 3, aDate)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Else
            aDate = DateAdd("d", 1, aDate)
        End If
        If MonthName(Month(aDate)) <> Range("B2").Value Then Exit Sub
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid Date", vbCritical, "Invalid Date!"
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Of course, this could be modified to assume that you select the first of the month on the cell - or it could attempt to figure out the first of the month for you to begin by starting at the top, but this just seemed simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

### Display the date in reference to the weekdays

Let's use an Excel formula:

```
=LET(
WeekRange; A6:A34;
WeekInterval; 6;
ThisMonth; MATCH(B2; {"January";"February";"March";"April";"May";"June";"July";"August";"September";"October";"November";"December"};);
ThisYear; B3;
WeekNames; {"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday"};
FirstDay; DATE(ThisYear; ThisMonth; 1);
LastDay; EOMONTH(FirstDay; 0);
FirstWorkDay; WORKDAY(EOMONTH(FirstDay; -1); 1);
WeekShift; WEEKDAY(FirstWorkDay; 2);
WeekInMonth; QUOTIENT(ROW(WeekRange) - INDEX(ROW(WeekRange); 1); WeekInterval);
WorkDays; IFNA(FirstWorkDay - WeekShift + MATCH(WeekRange;WeekNames;0) + 7*WeekInMonth; "");
TEXT(WorkDays; "[<" & FirstDay & "] ;[>" & LastDay & "] ;dd.mm."))
```

Details:

- `WeekInterval` - the number of cells between the same weekdays
- `WeekShift` - the weekday of the first workday of the month starting from Monday
- `WeekInMonth` - a week number in `WeekRange`
- `IFNA(...; "")` - put an empty string next to the `"Sum:"`
- `"[<FirstDay] ;[>LastDay] ;dd.mm."` - display a space when a date is outside the month (keep spaces after closing square brackets `]`)
- I use semicolon `;` as a separator due to my locale settings.

This formula has to be placed once next to the first Monday of the `WeekRange` (in your case in a cell `B6`). The result will be spilled on weekdays.

Comment: Nice formula. But unfortunately my employer has outdated Office 365 or what and formula "LET" is not working for now. I need to wait on update of Office.